# Highlighting Groups of Alternating Names in Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, formatting, spreadsheet, highlighting

I have been trying to find a good way to do this but it seems like I can not find a good Conditional Formatting formula to work with what I need. I am trying to do something along the lines of this with conditional formatting.

[image]

The spreadsheet I need to implement this on is pretty big but having this conditional formatting will make it easier to organize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=MOD((SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$13,$A$2:$A$13)))-SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF($A2:$A$13,$A2:$A$13)))+1),2)=0
```

Make sure to pay attention to what is and what is not relative reference.  This will not work if there are blank spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need a helper column. Put in that column the formula `=IF(<name>=<name in prev line>,1,-1)*<value from previous line>` (and a hard `1` in the first row). This will result in the sequence `1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,...` in the helper column, switching from 1 to -1 or back right whenever the name changes.

The conditional formula is then straightforward - make gray if =-1.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help! Can you just guide me on how to write the formula for the conditional formatting. I can't seem to understand how to highlight the whole row. Thank you!

Comment: Select the complete area, and then write your conditional formula for the _first_ cell: `=$C2=-1`. C2 would be the first cell in the helper column with the 1s and -1s, replace C with your column. Note the `$` sign before the C but _not_ before the 2 - that means that _all_ your columns look fixed in column C for the decision, but each row looks in its own row.